# Spark: Merge sorted partitions

Tags: java, merge, apache-spark

I would like to merge sorted partitions locally (on driver).

I did `.mapPartitionsToPair()` on my data which created `Iterable<Tuple2<D,X>>` where `D` is a type that has ordering (lets say some kind of date), and `X` is a type with some merging rules. The result is ordered by `D` uniquely.

I need my final result as the reduction of these partitions, also be ordered by `D` uniquely. Is there any local reduction that counts on the input to be ordered by key? Can I use any other approach to reach my goal?

I'm using Spark 1.1.0.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest solution is to `sortByKey()` and then `collect()`. It does not make use of the already-sorted property of the data, but the sort is scalable and [fast](https://databricks.com/blog/2014/10/10/spark-petabyte-sort.html), and it's easy to do.

But if you really want to rely on the already-sorted property, use `glom()` and then `collect()` to get the list of partitions. Then merge the sorted lists, for example with Guava's [Iterators.mergeSorted()](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Iterators.html#mergeSorted(java.lang.Iterable,%20java.util.Comparator)).